# replace older version of libgmp with a just compiled new one

Tags: linux, g++, debian, gmp

i just compiled new version 5.1 of `http://gmplib.org/` . the libraries seems to be in `/usr/local/lib`

how can i replace the old libraries of gmp, which are in `/usr/lib`? or can i simply put in some parameter when compiling a program with `g++`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When running `./configure` for the gmp library, add the argument `--prefix=/usr`

Comment: how do i remove the old library? (on debian) i still see it being used by my program with `lsof -n|grep libgmp.so`

Comment: check that ``readlink /usr/lib/libgmp.so`` still points to the debian version of libgmp, if it does then run ``sudo apt-get purge libgmp`` to get rid of it.